# Add margin-top to image inside html table

Tags: css, asp.net, html, html-table

I have the following html structure where I am displaying some details inside an html table.

```
<table cellspacing="15">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="Images/user1.png" />
            <label>
                User</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            John
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="Images/version1.png" />
            <label>
                Old ID</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            345345
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="Images/version3.png" />
            <label>
                New ID</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            367976
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Sample ScreenShot]

I want to add margin-top to the image so that the image will be shifted downward by some 3 or 4 pixel but the CSS is not having any effect. Please help.

Also I found that cellspacing is not a valid attribute in HTML5. Any alternate property to achieve the same effect.?

Comment: can you please share your css or a jsfiddle.net will be helpful to recreate your problem.

Comment: Do you want image and label should be placed in the same line?

Comment: It is working for me by adding margin-top: 3px to the class, table td img

Comment: sse my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hWLeV/

Comment: Its working. Which browser are you looking at ?? - @steeve

Comment: This also pushes down the text next to it, assuming the asker does not want this to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Adding a negative bottom margin to your image** 
(I generally avoid using negative margins as much as possible, but in this case it's a quick fix and won't effect the text next to it) :

```
td img {
    margin-bottom:-4px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its working for me.. Anyhow you can try like this **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/vB27A/)**,  if you want to place img and text in same line

**CSS:**

```
td,td img {
    line-height:28px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: I suggest this method, as a general rule of thumb.  However if you get super nit-picky over a couple pixels, you may have to play with the negative margins OR have some blank space at the top within your image.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative for `cellspacing` is

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 15px;
}
```

**Aligning image:**

You can use `vertical-align:middle`.

[**See DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3XFdQ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Margin-top should work correctly, but it probably moves down tha label too.

Possible solution is to use positioning, so:

```
img {position: relative; top: 4px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this.
Just remove `<lable>` tag & add `valign="top"` in `<td>`

```
<table cellspacing="15">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="Images/user1.png" />

                User
        </td>
        <td>
            John
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="Images/version1.png" />

                Old ID
        </td>
        <td>
            345345
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="Images/version3.png" />

                New ID
        </td>
        <td>
            367976
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```